# Family owls in Harry Potter

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

In Harry Potter, many Wizarding Families have owls. I'm assuming these owls don't stay in their cages all the time, so where do they live? Would the families have a room/owlery for them? Or would they just be free to sleep anywhere in the house? 
And do these owls need feeding by their owners, or would they just hunt and be able to feed themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall any mention of family owls having cages in any of the books except when they are travelling. Pigwigeon flew around Ron's room a lot which makes me think he probably slept there. I think JKR wanted a world where the animals were quite close to their wizard companions so most owls probably did live around the house (though it would depend on the family, I doubt Draco Malfoy's eagle owl shared his room).
As for feeding, I suspect that they all do what Hedwig did in the series - eat a mixture of owl pellets (sold in Diagon Alley for example) and hunt for prey.

Comment: The Malfoys probably were rich enough to have an an Owlery of sorts in their home- the Weasleys were not.

Answer (score 4):

In the Weasley household, the family owl Errol seems to live in the communal rooms. He has a perch in the kitchen, near the back door, but may also be found flopped out on a chair or on the draining board.

From *HP and the Chamber of Secrets*:

> "Morning, all," said Percy briskly. "Lovely day."
>
> He sat down in the only remaining chair but leapt up again almost immediately, pulling from underneath him a moulting, gray feather duster - at least, that was what Harry thought it was, until he saw that it was breathing.
>
> "Errol!" said Ron, taking the limp owl from Percy and extracting a letter from under its wing. "Finally - he's got Hermione's answer. I wrote to her saying we were going to try and rescue you from the Dursleys."
>
> He carried Errol to a perch just inside the back door and tried to stand him on it, but Errol flopped straight off again so Ron lay him on the draining board instead, muttering, "Pathetic."

As for feeding, @ThruGog is probably right: they're partially fed by their owners at home and also go out to hunt themselves. In Errol's case, he might be too feeble to be able to hunt much, so the Weasleys probably feed him mainly on owl pellets.

Comment: Are you ever going to finish that last sentence? ;-þ

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not sure what happened there! I can't remember what I was planning to say, but I've filled in that sentence now. Nice þorn by the way ;-)

Comment: Þorns just seem so much more anatomically correct than p’s.